# Variable value get empty in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, properties

I have create computed property for store the strTokenValue and send it to the web services.

```
   private var strTokenValue = String()
    var tokenValue: String {
        get {
            if strTokenValue != "" {
                return strTokenValue
            }
            else {
                if let token = StrongBoxController.sharedInstance.keychainStore.unarchive(objectForKey: "TokenValue") as? Data {
                    strTokenValue = StrongBoxController.sharedInstance.convertDataToString(value: token)
                    return strTokenValue
                }
                else {
                    return ""
                }
            }
        }
        set {
            strTokenValue = ""
            StrongBoxController.sharedInstance.saveValues(value: "\(newValue)", key: “TokenValue”)
        }
    }
```

1. We have send every user action Asynchronously and we have not wait for success response for track function web services, So i have not added success and failure response in the below code.

   ```
   func track(actionTaken: String,incidentNumber: String,message: String,completion:@escaping(_ success: Bool, _ error: String,_ actionTakenName: String) -> Void ) {
           DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
               let url = "\(ServerCommunication.sharedInstance.getDomainBaseUrl())api/track"
               let parameters = [
                   “token_value” : self.tokenValue,
                   "device_os":"iOS",
                   "device_type": UIDevice.modelName,
                   "action_taken": actionTaken,
                   "message" : message,
               ]
          }
    }
   ```
2. We have called the one more web service to send the image and tokenValue.

> Request:
>
> ```
>       “token_value” : “”,
>         "device_os":"iOS",
>         "device_type": “iPhone X”,
>         "action_taken": “Image captured”,
>         "message" : “”,
> ```

```
func convertDataToString(value: Data) -> String {
    return String(decoding: value, as: UTF8.self)
}



public func unarchive(objectForKey key:String) -> Any? {
    guard let data = self.data(forKey: key) else {
        return nil
    }

    let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data as Data)
    return unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: key)
}


 @objc func saveValues(value : String, key: String) {
  _ = self.keychainStore.archive(convertStringToData(value: value), key: key, accessibility: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly)
 }
```

**Both web services called simultaneously and “tokenValue” get empty in trackActions web services in some scenarios**

Comment: Off-topic, I think a computed property should be pretty simple and with no performance issues so if you are reading persisted values in your code like it looks I think it should be a function instead

Comment: Can you post the code of `StrongBoxController.sharedInstance.keychainStore.unarchive(objectForKey:)` and `StrongBoxController.sharedInstance.saveValues(value: "\(newValue)", key: “TokenValue”)`?
I think it is no thing to do with computed property but the way you save and restore the value.

Comment: You forgot the save method

Comment: @HarikarthickKconvertStringToData no definition of self.data and convertStringToData

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that you save data using `convertStringToData` which doesn't probably use `convertStringToData`. I think so because of `convertDataToString` doesn't use `NSKeyedAarchiver`.
In order to resolve, you should use `unarchive`.
 To save the data use

```
func convertDataToString(value: Data) -> String? {
        return String(data: value, encoding: .utf8)
    }
    func convertStringToData(value: String) -> Data? {
        return value.data(using: .utf8)
    }
```

and

```
keychainStore.archive(convertStringToData(value: value), key: key, accessibility: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly)


stored = convertDataToString(StrongBoxController.sharedInstance.keychainStore.unarchive(objectForKey: "TokenValue"))
```